# PHP insert ad after X paragraphs, then every Y paragraphs if the text is long enough

Tags: php, html, string

I need to insert an ad code at intervals in this way:

1. `$insert_every_paragraphs` is a variable that indicates how often a paragraph should appear in the text. 10, for example.
2. `$minimum_paragraph_count` is used to see if the text is long enough for any ads, and **also** the very first ad should appear after this many paragraphs (then it should repeat the intervals in #1). 4, for example.
3. The ad codes work like this: x100, x101, x102, x103, etc. Users can set how many are eligible to be added. They render like `[cms_ad:x100]` and PHP replaces them later (that part works fine).
4. The code should stop adding ads once it gets to the end of #3. That is, even if it has enough paragraphs to keep adding ads, it should stop if it has reached x104 (in this example).

So in this example, it would work like this: after 4 paragraphs, insert x100. Then, every 10 paragraphs, insert another until x103 has been inserted. Don't insert x104, even if there are 100 paragraphs. But also, if there aren't at least 34 paragraphs, x103 would never appear.

What I have so far is this:

```
$paragraph_end = '</p>';

$insert_every_paragraphs = 10;
$minimum_paragraph_count = 4;

$embed_prefix      = 'x';
$start_embed_id    = 'x100';
$start_embed_count = intval( str_replace( $embed_prefix, '', $start_embed_id ) ); // ex 100
$end_embed_id      = 'x103';
$end_embed_count   = intval( str_replace( $embed_prefix, '', $end_embed_id ) ); // ex 104

$paragraph_positions = array();
$last_position       = -1;

while ( stripos( $content, $paragraph_end, $last_position + 1 ) !== false ) {
    // Get the position of the end of the next $paragraph_end.
    $last_position         = stripos( $content, $paragraph_end, $last_position + 1 ) + 3;
    $paragraph_positions[] = $last_position;
}

// If the total number of paragraphs is bigger than the minimum number of paragraphs
if ( count( $paragraph_positions ) >= $minimum_paragraph_count ) {
    // How many ads have been added?
    $n = $start_embed_count;
    // Store the position of the last insertion.
    $previous_position = $start_embed_count;
    $i                 = 0;
    while ( $i < count( $paragraph_positions ) && $n <= $end_embed_count ) {

        if ( 0 === ( $i + 1 ) % $insert_every_paragraphs && isset( $paragraph_positions[ $i ] ) ) {
            $shortcode = "\n" . '[cms_ad:' . $embed_prefix . (int) $n . ']' . "\n";

            $position = $paragraph_positions[ $i ] + 1;

            if ( $position > $previous_position ) {
                $content = substr_replace( $content, $shortcode, $paragraph_positions[ $i ] + 1, 0 );
                // Increase the saved last position.
                $previous_position = $position;
                // Increment number of shortcodes added to the post.
                $n++;
            }
            // Increase the position of later shortcodes by the length of the current shortcode.
            foreach ( $paragraph_positions as $j => $pp ) {
                if ( $j > $i ) {
                    $paragraph_positions[ $j ] = $pp + strlen( $shortcode );
                }
            }
        }
        $i++;
    }
}
```

I thought this was working okay when the numbers were 4 and 6 instead of 4 and 10, but the error became clear when I started adjusting the values. It currently inserts an ad every 10 paragraphs, and of course it does not insert an ad after the fourth paragraph.

I'm not opposed to using `explode` or other methods for this, of course, but this was what got me the farthest.

Comment: _sidenote:_ in your posted code there's a `;` missing at `$start_embed_id    = 'x100'`

Comment: _"and also the very first ad should appear after this many paragraphs"_ is the main problem, right?

Comment: @Jeff thanks, I got too eager with cleaning up stuff. But yes, the main problem is the very first ad after this may paragraphs.

Comment: So if the first ad was after paragraph 4, is the second ad after paragraph 10 or paragraph 14?

Comment: @Anthony if the first ad was after paragraph 4, the second would be after paragraph 14.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not split the paragraphs into an array, add the ads, then join it together again.
It will remove most of the string-concatination headache.

Please note i did not implement the formatting of the shortcode.

```
$insert_every_paragraphs = 2;
$minimum_paragraph_count = 1;
$adcodes = ['x100', 'x101', 'x102', 'x103'];

$paragraphs = [];
$split = explode('</p>',$content);
foreach($split as $paragraph){
  //filter out empty paragraphs
  if(strlen($paragraph)>3)
      $paragraphs[] = $paragraph . '</p>';
}

$paragraph_count = count($paragraphs);
$ad_num = 0;

$counter = $minimum_paragraph_count;
for($i=0;$i<$paragraph_count;$i++){
    if($counter==0){
        $adcode = $adcodes[$ad_num];
        $shortcode = "[cms_ad:$adcode]";

        array_splice($paragraphs,$i+$ad_num,0,$shortcode);
        $counter = $insert_every_paragraphs;
        $ad_num++;

        if($ad_num>=count($adcodes))
            break;
    }
    $counter--;
}


$content = implode('',$paragraphs);
```

Comment: I think this might work except the `$maximum_ads` variable is dynamic depending on how long the content is. Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: It occurred to me I could count the maximum ads like this:
`$paragraph_count = count( $paragraphs );`
`$maximum_ads     = floor( ( $paragraph_count - $minimum_paragraph_count ) / $insert_every_paragraphs ) + $minimum_paragraph_count;`

Does this seem reasonable?

Comment: @JonathanStegall I'm don't think I understand what you mean by the maximum ad number being dynamic based on the content length. In your post you stated 'once it gets to the end of #3', which basically means 4 ads?

Comment: Oh, sorry. When I said #3 I meant the 3rd bullet point in my list. I was unclear there. Basically, there's a list of ad codes (x100, x101, x102, x103, up to x110). This is what I didn't articulate well. The content should contain as many ads as it can, based on the `$minimum_paragraph_count` and the `$insert_every_paragraphs`. So if minimum was 4 and the insert every was 10, there'd be an ad after the 4th paragraph, then an ad every 10 paragraphs until it ran through the full list, or until the content was finished.

Comment: @JonathanStegall ok now i got it. the snippet is updated.

Comment: Hi @ManuelOtto do you think you can filter out paragraphs with a given class or classes? I'm testing to replace my actual snnipet to "insert ads after x paragraphs" using PHP and your code works like a charm in my tests. But in my system there some paragraphs with classes that I don't want to replace because they are part of some gadget. So i.e. <p class="content-gadget"> would be skiped. Anyway thank you by this simple and functional snippet.

Comment: @FelipeLima you could do it very cheaply by just checking if the name of such class can be found anywhere in the paragraph split. at the same place where the above code checks for empty paragraphs, add something like `strpos($paragraph, 'exception-class')`